# How to change ckeditor mode from inline to standard in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in inline mode in my site pages. However the ckeditor does not provide the functionality of Source mode when used in inline editing mode. One of my pages needs that functionality.

I want to change the ckeditor mode from inline to standard when that page is loaded using Javascript.

I tried doing .attr('contentEditable', false) but it still keeps the inline mode there with the buttons disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor does provide a source editing feature for inline editors. Just add the [sourcedialog](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcedialog) plugin to your build.